# How to update Html content present in string based on Id using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 1. Html String Variable 2. Object containing changes

```
var htmlString = '\<body>\
                    <div class="shrek">\
                        <div class="trck">Object containing\
                            <div id ="head"> \
                                <strong>Object containing</strong>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div id ="body"> String Variable String Variable String Variable</div>\
                    <div id ="foot">Similar Questions</div>\
                  </body>'

var obj = {
    'head': '<strong>I</strong> am new head'
}
```

I want to update the htmlString with new content and pass this variable to service.
At end htmlstring should be like

```
<body>
    <div class="shrek">
        <div class="trck">Object containing
            <div id="head"><strong>I</strong> am new head</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="body"> String Variable String Variable String Variable</div>
    <div id="foot">Similar Questions</div>
</body>
```

HtmlString pattern can be different, how can I update the string by based on Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create DOM tree in memory and manipulate with this tree with any freedom you want.

```
parser = new DOMParser(),
doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
```

In this example you can find element by ID, update content, remove if necessary and then produce result HTML.

```
var element = doc.getElementById("head");
```

Please see example below:

```js
var xmlString = `<body>
<div class="shrek"><div class="trck">Object containing<div id ="head"> <strong>Object containing</strong></div></div></div>
<div id ="body"> String Variable String Variable String Variable</div>
<div id ="foot">Similar Questions</div>
</body>`, 
   parser = new DOMParser(),
   doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
  
var element = doc.getElementById("head");
element.innerHTML = '<strong>I</strong> am new head';

console.log(doc.documentElement.outerHTML);
```

Comment: Only Change is text/html

Answer (score 2):

Firstly be careful with your quotes as you have several mis-matched instances. I'd suggest using `'` to delimit the string so that you can use `"` within it to delimit the attribute values in your HTML.

To solve your actual issue you can use `Object.keys()` to get the keys from the object, which contain the `id` attributes to search for, before looping over them to retrieve the elements and set the `html()` as needed. Try this:

```js
var htmlString = '<div class="shrek"><div class="trck">Object containing<div id="head"><strong>Object containing</strong></div></div></div><div id="body"> String Variable String Variable StringVariable</div><div id="foot">Similar Questions</div>';
var obj = {
  'head': '<strong>I</strong> am new head'
}

var $html = $(htmlString);
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
  $html.find('#' + k).html(obj[k]);
});
$html.appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your String is invalid, since you have some double quotes in there. An easy fix is to use backticks instead.

Then, you can transform your String into a Jquery object via `$(...)`.

You can then loop through your `obj` and update your HTML accordingly.

```js
var htmlString = `<body>
<div class="shrek"><div class="trck">Object containing<div id ="head"> <strong>Object containing</strong></div></div></div>
<div id ="body"> String Variable String Variable String Variable</div>
<div id ="foot">Similar Questions</div>
</body>`;

var obj = {
'head':'<strong>I</strong> am new head'
}

var html = $(htmlString);

$.each(obj,function(id,val){
  $('#'+id,html).html(val);
});

$('body').append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want entire HTML content starting from body and variable should be updated

Comment: @KunalVashist It's inside your `html` variable. I'll append it to the example.